# Error in Python after I click the stop button

Tags: python

Please help me, I'm a beginner at Python. Everything is good when I run my code but there is an error after I click the stop button. How can I resolve this problem?

**Code:**

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# read data using pin 17
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=17)

while True:
    result = instance.read()
    if result.is_valid():
        print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
        print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

    time.sleep(2)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> %Run dht11_example.py
  Last valid input : 2018-07-08 02:33:31. 993427
  Temperature : 30 C
  Humidity : 52%

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "path/file.py", line 21, in <module>
      time.sleep(2)
  KeyboardInterrupt: Execution Interrupted

>>>
```

**Error:**

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "path/file.py", line 21, in <module>
      time.sleep(2)
  KeyboardInterrupt: Execution Interrupted
```

Answer (score 1):

You've just misunderstood what `KeyboardInterrupt` means. To quote from [the relevant Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html):

> *exception* **KeyboardInterrupt**
>
> > Raised when the user hits the interrupt key (normally `Control-C` or `Delete`). During execution, a check for interrupts is made regularly. The exception inherits from `BaseException` so as to not be accidentally caught by code that catches `Exception` and thus prevent the interpreter from exiting.

In this case, your "interrupt key" is just your IDE's stop button, rather than any keyboard shortcut. You didn't make any mistakes. I do think your IDE shouldn't be showing that, though, since it's not really an error, and it makes it seem like one. You can safely ignore this error, or follow [blhsing's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228284/1863564) and wrap your code in a `try` / `except KeyboardInterrupt` to make it look prettier. Frankly, I wouldn't, but it's ultimately a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The `KeyboardInterrupt` exception is raised when you manually abort the execution of the script with ctrl-C, so it isn't really an error, but you can make it exit gracefully when ctrl-C is pressed by catching the exception in a `try` block.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import dht11
import time
import datetime

# initialize GPIO
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.cleanup()

# read data using pin 17
instance = dht11.DHT11(pin=17)

try:
    while True:
        result = instance.read()
        if result.is_valid():
            print("Last valid input: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
            print("Temperature: %d C" % result.temperature)
            print("Humidity: %d %%" % result.humidity)

        time.sleep(2)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Done.')
```

Comment: Hah, beat you by like six seconds! (No, it wasn't a race, but still.)